# Can one use a 26" tube in a 27.5" tire or a 27.5" tube in a 29" tire?

Tags: tire, wheels, innertube

I upgraded my bike but have a bunch of old tubes lying around. Can I use them?

Comment: OK for 'track side' get you home repairs, but i would not leave the wrong sized tube in. Me and mates some times 'share' spared and tools to save weight, We carry a  couple of spare 27.5" in the group to which covers the 26 and 29ers.

Comment: If you want to get use out of old tubes donate them to a local bike coop, bikes for kids or similar charity, or list 'em for free on Craigslist or your local Facebook bike marketplace.

Comment: Note that tube width is also an issue.  A tube of say 1.25 inch width will usually work up to maybe 1.75 inch, but you get much more difference than that and you will have problems.  And fitting a wide tube in a narrow tire will often result in tube failure due to the tube folding up on itself.

Answer (score 1):

yes I'm pretty sure it should work. have not tried it myself but when you pump up a tube outside of the tire the diameter increases quite a lot (so the change in diameter from 26-27.5 or from 27.5-29") should not be an issue imo.

Comment: +1. A slightly smaller MTB tube in a bigger MTB tire will work. There is a limit to it, of course. I recently tried to fit a tube marked as 27.5" × 2.4" into a fatbike tire of 26"×4.8" dimensions. I managed to inflate it and everything looked fine when I left it for the night. In the morning the tube was split in shreds. Silly me.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov yes indeed when you put a bigger tube into a smaller tire the tube will fold over onto itself which usually results in a blown tube when riding

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov that might be a decent related but new question - your 26" fatbike tyre is asking a lot to go from 2.4" to 4.8"